# How do I add my Magento extension to Magento Connect store?

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I have developed some extension for Magento. If I found it as useful for someone:

1. how can I add that extension to Magento Connect?
2. Is there some kind of requirements and specifications?
3. Do someone expertise my extensions and approve it before adding to pool?
4. How do I sell and what requirements for merchandising?

Please provide some guide, thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very detailed information regarding publishing  your extension on Magento Connect.

You can refer to the [PDF](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf). It will give you detailed information regarding it.